# HTTP on localhost not working with DNS A-record and port forward (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Tags: networking, dns, browser, port-forwarding, localhost

I have a Jenkins server on my local machine that I publish to the outside world through a DNS A record (ci.alanif.se:8080) with my ISP and port forwarding through two routers.

This works perfectly fine from the outside and from any machine on my local network except my local machine, where, if I use the exact same URL, a browser typically says:

```
Server did not send any data (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)
```

Why is this and how can I fix it?

It is definitely not a browser issue (cache, cookies, ...) since installing a completely virgin browser also exhibits this behaviour. So I'm suspecting the port forwarding somehow. A loop?

Comment: Which exactly is the url you use locally?

Comment: I want to use the exact same URL, but that is exactly the thing that that does not work. Clearified that in the question.

Comment: Try adding "ci.alanif.se" with address 127.0.0.1 to your hosts file

Comment: Yes, that would of course work, but I'm also trying to learn something here.

Comment: check to which ip "ci.alanif.se" is resolved both on your machine and on one of the other machines on the local network that you say are working correctly

Comment: Same: 81.233.118.11 and pings just fine on both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite common that port forwarding don't work when trying to access services from the internal network. The behaviour varies from device to device.

It's a bit strange that machines on the same network (your machine and other in the local network you made tests from) behave differently: it could be a corner case in the implementation of port fowarding on your router, occurring only when the source IP is the same as the port forwarding destination, but I'm just guessing.

The most common solution for your use case is to configure your local DNS server to resolve (only internally) the public host name to the internal IP address.

As a benefit that avoids having local traffic forced through the router.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sharing your experiences.